# Stanford CoreNLP : Get CharacterOffset Annotation from Parse Tree

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

Using the parser output from another parser, I have created the parse tree for a sentence. Now, I need to find the character offset for each Noun Phrase that occurs in the parse.

How can I go about that?

Comment: If you are using "another parser" why is your question tagged stanford-nlp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a subtree that corresponds to a Noun Phrase. Get the leaves of this tree:

```
List<Tree> leaves = tree.getLeaves();
```

Then take the starting point of the first leaf (*CharacterOffsetBeginAnnotation* value) and the end point of the last leaf (*CharacterOffsetEndAnnotation*). The resulting interval is the offset of an NP.

To get the offset value, take the leaf's label and cast it to HasOffset:

```
Label label = firstLeaf.label();
HasOffset ofs = (HasOffset) label;
int start = ofs.beginPosition();
```

This works for Stanford CoreNLP 3.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by looking into the tokenizer/chunker used by your parser. I'd be easier to find a character offset mapping between chunks and your raw text (if the character offset is not already there). Then you can traverse your parse tree looking for noun phrases and from there traverse left-hand branches until you reach a leave, which will be the first token in your parse tree; and from the NP node, traverse right-hand branches until you reach another leave which will be your ending token. You can get the offset of the first token by counting leaves from the root of your tree.